# How to do image validation by using selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am new to selenium webdriver.Can any one please help how to validate an image by selenium web driver.

Regards,
Manasa

Comment: What does "validate an image" mean?

Comment: I have to validate whether image is present or not on the web page?

Comment: Which language are you using (ie ruby, java, etc.)?

Comment: I am using java to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the image in the HTML
2. Write a selector for it
3. Assert that `driver.findElements(By.Selector("coolstuff")).size()` is 0 (if not present), or greater than 0 (if present)